# following the majority

Tags: discussion, down-votes

The Drashoth Haran says that the majority has a greater probability of being right. This is true in the Sanhedrin. But what about the down-votes here in our forum?

Sometimes I do not understand why one question or answer displeases more than another. I could tell myself that there is no need for competence to vote. I want to ask the specialists. How do they react to the votes given to them? (I speak in Mi Yodeya, no professional sites). Should they adapt their style based on votes?

Comment: Please ensure that my edit matches your intent. Perhaps others (whose English is better) should weigh in on that question also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36962/discussion-between-kouty-and-msh210).

Answer (score 4):

I think that it is a good idea, in general, to attempt to adapt one's style based on votes. You are basically correct that pretty much anybody can vote ([you need](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) 125 reputation points to vote down, which is not a lot), but in my experience most downvoters--especially here on Mi Yodeya--are quite competent and good about giving feedback when they think a post is not of the highest quality. When posts are downvoted, I think it is generally a good idea to follow the advice of those who comment on the post with suggestions, and to keep that advice in mind for future posts.

It's important to remember that there really aren't rules for when you should vote up or down on a post. People can choose to vote however they wish for whatever reason they wish. Downvotes might not necessarily be because the information in the post is *wrong*. In your case, I don't think that's usually the reason you sometimes have downvoted posts. From what I have gathered from your contributions, it does seem like you have a good deal of Torah knowledge to share. The problem with many of your posts, though, is that the English is very difficult to understand. The original formulation of this question is a perfect example of this. I understand that you are likely not a native English speaker and I would never *blame* you for this. Remember that votes are **not** personal and should not be taken as a measurement of your individual worth. If a post is very difficult to understand, there is a good chance it will be downvoted. That's true for even the highest-ranked users here. Every post is judged on its own merits.

My suggestion to you is to continue to provide the great Torah information that you have been providing so far, but to work on your English writing. Posting here should actually be good practice. When people react negatively to your posts because of the language barrier, take the opportunity to try to clean them up and make them easier to read.

Comment: IME having received one downote is not necessarily statistically significant, but having received two is.

Comment: @DoubleAA, The Drashoth Haran...?

Answer (score 1):

After a 1 & 1/2 month of experience I can answer myself:

1. Feedbacks are very important. They are due to 2 factors, interesting or not (in a book store there are best sellers and other books, every book has his importance and contributes to make the store a good store), true or not, good finish;
2. May be a good work with few feedback, perhaps because most people are not interested with the topic. May be that the post needed a lot of work but is not clear or wrong or too hard to read.
3. May be a simple post with a beautiful topic, or very important, or with practical utility. It will receive a great number of feedbacks.

   ---

   For me the number points do not be compass. If a topic is not very popular and need big work and it is important for me, I make this for me, hoping that someone will enjoy with this. Even if this post is already and apparently definitively downvoted, I do my best until I am sure that the answer is really true.
4. Downvoting generally are a problem when they are >= 2 as said @DoubleAA. With my short experience I agree.
5. Each of us has his personal reasons why he stay in the website. It is very complex psychologically, socio... and not allways relevant. Every people may find a common ground with several members and it is sufficient to take advantage of mi yodeya.
6. I love this website. The general mentallity is wonderfull. "מי כעמך ישראל". If this help to learn even one word of Tora it is Geant.